# Multiple select - size attribute cannot be applied

Tags: css, select

I have `<select multiple="multiple">..</select>` select and I also have `select{heigth: 30px;}` in some stylesheet that I cannot edit. Now my multiple select have 1-row heigth - "size" attribute cannot be applied. How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, first off - I'm assuming that you're using the `height` property, not the misspelled *`heigth`* property. There's two ways you could solve this.
The first (which I don't recommend) is by simply appending the style to the HTML element, like below:

```
<select multiple="multiple" style="height:100px">..</select>
```

Or, instead, my suggestion would be making a second style sheet, that uses the following property, including the "!important", which follows the attribute value:

```
select {
    height: 100px !important;
}
```

Doing it like such will override the original style, and replace it. This isn't the only method that you can use to override it - you can [read here on CSS specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/).

Comment: I want to stress the importance of avoiding the use of !important (no pun intended).  When you get into the habit of adding !important to style declarations, you end up with a very hard to trace spaghetti of style rules.  Only use !important when you need to override styles that were declared inline (on the HTML element itself) and you are not able to change/remove that inline style. Also don't use generic selectors like 'select' for such specific declarations as 'height: 100px', because such rules will target *all* select boxes in your entire website. Follow the advice of morgar instead.

Comment: Following from this is the second advice: Don't use inline style declarations right there in the HTML unless there is no easy other way, because it forces people to use !important later if they want to override it.

Answer (score 8):

I like the clean solution.

```
select[multiple] {
    height: 100px;

}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed, but be warned that this does not (yet) work in all browsers.

Comment: Realy? I work a lot with a eternet, than I don't have this problems. Sorry.

Comment: I just checked, but it seems that as of IE7 onwards, browser support is pretty ubiquitous, so it seems it is now ok to use this as long as you don't need to support IE6. +1

Answer (score 2):

I think the right way should be adding a class to the specific `<select>` and giving it the right size, like:

`<select multiple="multiple" class="multiple">`

```
select.multiple {
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This would also work. As long as the select element has a higher priority than the one defined in the other stylesheet.

Comment: Why clutter the DOM?  `select[multilple="multiple"] { height: 100px; }`