# Django: Include/Exclude Push/Pull Template for ManyToMany Relationship

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship in Django where one lesson may be linked to many (~20) objectives.   In total there are over 100 objectives that can be selected that are categorised in two ways.  The default combobox size make it difficult to select and view the objectives.  Due to the nature of the application (curriculum and lesson planning tool) most of the work is done in admin and it would be useful to view the currently selected objectives better.

I would like something that looked like this:

[image: Adding additional fields]

[Link if image not shown](http://www.databasedev.co.uk/image/find-dup-extra-field-list.gif)

but would settle on viewing more fields at once and/or ideally sorted by those fields selected?

I would be grateful for any help, ideas or examples from the more experience Django developers here.  Thanks in advance of your time.

Chris

Comment: So I have found a partial answer for my query.  I could use the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6013279/multiple-select-size-attribute-cannot-be-applied to increase the height and number of options shown but this is still rather inelegant given the number of rows being dealt with.  Any improvements on this answer would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily, a very similar widget is already provided for use in the admin - just set the `filter_horizontal` attribute in your admin class:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Lesson
    filter_horizontal = ('objectives',)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal).

Comment: Daniel, you are a legend.  Thanks.   Only thing to mention and it might be why you have that comma at the end is that it has to be list or tuple.   I wrapped 'objectives' in square brackets and this also worked.   Thanks again.